# Using Ruby, what is a simple way to count how many true in each column of n x m array?

Tags: ruby

Given an `n` x `m` array of boolean:

```
[[true, true, false],
 [false, true, true],
 [false, true, true]]
```

what is a simple way that can return "how many true are there in that column?"

the result should be

```
[1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: In case anyone is interested, in Python it's: `map(sum,zip(*a))`

Comment: You asked for **shortest code**, but that wasn't really what you wanted, was it? ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use transpose to get an array where each subarray represents a column and then map each column to the number of `true`s in it:

```
arr.transpose.map {|subarr| subarr.count(true) }
```

Here's a version with inject that should run on 1.8.6 without any dependencies:

```
arr.transpose.map {|subarr| subarr.inject(0) {|s,x| x ? s+1 : s} }
```

Comment: It works in 1.8.7, too. For 1.8.6 you can probably get the count method from backports or active_support. If that's not an option, you can write it using inject.

Comment: Elegant, but not very verbose. +1 anyway.

Comment: seems like you can also use:
    count(true)
instead of:
    count{|x| x}

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[true, true, false],
         [false, true, true],
         [false, true, true]]
array.transpose.map {|x| x.count {|y| y}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
b.transpose.collect{|x| x.reject{|y| y != true}.length}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[true, true, false],
   [false, true, true],
   [false, true, true]]

a.transpose.map{|c|c.count(true)}
```

sneaky way of saving one more character

```
a.transpose.map{|c|c.count(!!0)}
```

As Jonas points out it is possible to golf this some more

```
a.transpose.map{|c|c.count !!0}
```

Comment: You can save two more with `a.transpose.map{|c|c.count !!0}`